# How to refer to parameters.yml in services.yml?

Tags: symfony, service, configuration, parameters

Here are params.

**app/config/parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    test:
        enabled:     true
        validate:    true
```

And this is service which I want to configure with test param from previous file.

**MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: "parameters.yml" }

parameters:

services:
    my.form.type:
        class: My\Bundle\Form\Type\MyType
        arguments:
            - %test%
```

Import doesn't work this way. How should I do it?

PS I know I can refer to @service_container. But the point is to pass array explicitly via yaml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can ommit ...

```
imports:
    - { resource: "parameters.yml" }

parameters:
```

... parameters.yml should automatically be parsed and the parameters should be available for injection if you surround them with `%`.

Try:

```
services:
    my.form.type:
        class: My\Bundle\Form\Type\MyType
        arguments: ["%test%"]
        alias: my_form_type
```

Comment: I thought **arguments: - %test%** and **arguments: ["%test%"]** should give same result

Comment: Any idea on this unanswered simple question Nifr? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937574/symfony2-extend-rememberme-success-handler - nobody else knows the answer

Comment: `%` can be used just inside a string, so it should be `"%test%"` in the first place. In my experience is possible to just refer to string parameters; if they are array they will throw an exception when trying to expand the array to a string value.