# Symfony2 - Extend RememberMe Success Handler

Tags: php, symfony

I want to perform one small PHP action after someone has just been logged in with the Remember Me feature in Symfony2.

I have seen this but not sure how to extend it:
    http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/RememberMe/PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.html

I'm not sure how to go about this (without editing the core code which of course wouldn't be good). I have added my own code to an AuthenticationSuccess handler for when they login via submitting a form, but that is simply by creating a service and specifying like example below, but I don't see an option for the RememberMe success handler and I can see the full list of options here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html.

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secure_area:
            form_login:
                success_handler: some.service.id
```

How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Users authenticated via remember me receive the role `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`.

Check your user's roles for this role in the normal success handler and perform the desired action.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know where to put some code that executes after they auto-login with the remember me option. As of now all I can think of is to edit the core Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices::loginSucess class/method. How do I extend this the best way without editing the core? The normal success handler doesn't fire when logging in with Remember Me.

Comment: Thanks for the initial answer Nifr. I'm really struggling on this and nobody seems to know the answer. I know you know loads about Symfony2 so if it can't be done then please tell me and I'll have to look at something else. Thanks again for your time.